# NSKeyedArchiver being called twice

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

When I look at the console while my iphone app is shutting down, it appears as though my encodewithcoder is being called twice. Even though I only encode an array of 'NewsItems' once.

Is this normal?

```
(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    NSLog(@"News encode called %@", self.title);    

    [encoder encodeObject:self.newsItemId forKey:KNewsItemNewsIdKey];   
    [encoder encodeObject:self.title forKey:KNewsItemTitleKey];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.author forKey:KNewsItemAuthorKey];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.description forKey:KNewsItemDescriptionKey];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.imageUrl forKey:KNewsItemImageUrlKey];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.thumbnailUrl forKey:KNewsItemThumbnailUrlKey];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.createdAt forKey:KNewsItemCreatedAtKey];

    //Images
    //convert from PNG to NSData, other method available for JPG
    NSData *savedImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.savedImage); 
    [encoder encodeObject:savedImageData forKey:KNewsItemSavedImageKey];

    NSData *thumbnailImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.savedThumbnail); 
    [encoder encodeObject:thumbnailImageData forKey:KNewsItemSavedThumbnailKey];

}


//code to encode
    [archiver encodeObject:self.newsArray forKey:KNewsArrayDataKey];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint on your `NSLog()` statement and check your stack trace to see who's calling you each time.